# How can I add tables to an already deployed SQL Server CE Database on a Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce, windows-phone-7.1

It's nice and simple to create a database if it doesn't already exist, via:

```
if (!context.DatabaseExists())
{
    // Create the local database.
    context.CreateDatabase();
}
```

But if a new table is added as part of an upgrade, is there anyway to do an in-place upgrade of the database on the phone to match the schema as if it had just been created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DatabaseSchemaUpdater class, see this walkthrough: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394022(v=VS.92).aspx