# How to make changes to a WP7 MVVM database without reinstalling app

Tags: database, windows-phone-7, mvvm

I'm using a MVVM database in a WP7 app. My problem is that when I change the core database (by adding another column etc) the app requires a reinstall, otherwise it just crashes.

If I release my app to the marketplace and then change the database, every user that updates will brick their app.

How do I make changes to the database without requiring a reinstall? Or is it a case where I can NEVER change the database structure?

The tutorial I originally followed is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286405(v=vs.92).aspx

Cheers,

Cameron

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add tables to an already deployed SQL Server CE Database on a Windows Phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869956/how-can-i-add-tables-to-an-already-deployed-sql-server-ce-database-on-a-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to change the database schema without breaking it using the techniques decribed at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860(v=vs.92).aspx in the section Changing database schema near the end of the article.